# i am not able to dual boot in Dell Inspiron 15z

Tags: dual-boot, inspiron

I have kept boot settings in legacy mode. After setting it when I go to boot setup and select USB drive in which I have Ubuntu 13.04. it asks:
1. Try Ubuntu
2. Install Ubuntu
3. ....
4. ....

When I click on Install Ubuntu, the process doesn't go ahead. It shows some errors like: `failed to read file. load kernel version first.`, but while in laptops like 15r and 17r some procedure followed it gets installed.
Please answer me why I am not able to dual boot.
Please send me step-by-step procedures of dual booting in the Dell Inspiron 15z.
Please reply, I'm in urgent need of Ubuntu dual booting.

Answer (score 0):

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 15R and my software is dual: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04.
I burned a dvd with the image of Ubuntu. Press F2 to boot your machine with the CD-DVD inserted as a first option. It runs and once restarted, without the disk, I can choose either Ubuntu or Windows. All software perfecly works.
Just follow these instructions: http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try with another image of Ubuntu, for that which you have may be corrupt.

[This is the link for Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit flavor](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=latest)

and this

[Ubuntu 13.04 for 64 bit flavor link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=latest)

but why do you want to try 12.04 LTS  version that comes with LTS "Long Term Support" in my opinion I think you have a great advantage over version 13.04.

Of course this does not mean that version 13.04 does not have much to offer and is not as stable as 12.04 but tastes not discussed here, depend exclusively what distribution you think suits you ... the most important is to choose one .You'll love it I assure you.

Comment: You should only use 64 bit version. and You should install in the same boot mode as Windows. If Windows is UEFI then turn off legacy/CSM mode and install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. If Windows is BIOS/CSM mode then install Ubuntu in BIOS mode. Otherwise the only way to dual boot is by going into UEFI menu and turning on or off UEFI for one system or the other. You may also want to look into Sputnik which are updates for Dell. Someone mentioned those updates are built into 13.04 now.